# c# fixed arrays - which structure is fastest to read from?

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, processing-efficiency

I have some large arrays of 2D data elements. A and B aren't equally sized dimensions.

A) is between 5 and 20

B) is between 1000 and 100000

The initialization time is no problem as its only going to be lookup tables for realtime application, so performance on indexing elements from knowing value A and B is crucial. The data stored is currently a single byte-value.

**I was thinking around these solutions:**

```
byte[A][B] datalist1a;
```

or

```
byte[B][A] datalist2a;
```

or

```
byte[A,B] datalist1b;
```

or

```
byte[B,A] datalist2b;
```

or perhaps loosing the multidimension as I know the fixed size and just multiply the to values before looking it up.

```
byte[A*Bmax + B] datalist3;
```

or

```
byte[B*Amax + A] datalist4;
```

What I need is to know, what datatype/array structure to use for most efficient lookup in C# when I have this setup.

**Edit 1**
the first two solutions were supposed to be multidimensional, not multi arrays.

**Edit 2**
All data in the smallest dimension is read at each lookup, but the large one is only used for indexing once at a time.

So its something like - Grab all A's from sample B.

Comment: Probably depends how you're stepping through the array when looking up values.

Comment: Have you also considered a two dimensional array: `byte[A,B]`? (The form `byte[A][B]` is an array of arrays.)

Comment: The first three rules of performance optimizations: Measure, measure, measure. Set up some kind of test environment that matches the production environment, and test them.

Comment: There is no single correct answer to this question in its current form. As @George mentions, it depends on how you access the array. Are you doing random access? sequential? If sequential, in which direction (ie. A-dimension or B-dimension) primarily? The best way to handle this is to write different versions of the code and profile it, and that's in fact the correct answer to any such "what is fastest" type questions anyway.

Comment: I was hoping someone knew this already from testing what kinda array lookup C# compiled into. It was merly an architectual question from my point of view, as most CPUs will handle this quickly anyway. But doing this millions of times each day might in the end save some CPU cycles.

Comment: @Richard - ups!... my fault, thats what I meant. Going to edit the question. Thanks!

Comment: @Richard Using multidimensional arrays in C# has a significant impact on its performance, they are implemented differently:http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/arrays.aspx

Comment: @Richard According to Jeffrey Richter's book, CLR via C#, 3rd edition, page 398 (for those who have the book), 2+-dimensional arrays are actually slower in many cases than jagged (`x[...][...]`) arrays, because the compiler can in many cases optimize the usage of single-dimension arrays much better than 2d-arrays. So again, don't fall into the trap of assumptions, always measure measure measure.

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen: I dont hope you call me lazy, but can you recommend a structure from my last edit, without messure?

Comment: Lets say I use the [][] syntax, should the large dimension (B) be the first or the last?

Comment: As I said before, *we* can't give you that answer because it depends on *your* program and how *it* accesses the array. You *really* need to measure this if you care this deep about your program performance. If you really want my advice, it would be to just leave it for now, come back to it if you feel it's a bottleneck later. One thing about measuring for performance is that in 9 out of 10 cases (in my experience), bottlenecks crop up where I least expect it, so even if you manage to optimize this code, it is likely that this won't be your primary bottleneck.

Comment: Sorry for being so ignorant, but back in old days, there was a significant difference between how I index memory from C/C++ like when pulling data from a VGA-memory on PC. I thought the same rules applied on C#. I use the large B for index/lookup and pull ALL data from A each time.

Comment: @Lasse: Note I *didn't* recommend them. It seems odd that they were not referenced.

Comment: There probably is a difference, but the question is - is it big enough to worry about? If you have another performance problem in your program which overshadows this one by an order of magnitude, you should fix that one first. And @Lasse V. Karlsen is right - the fastest approach will depend on the manner you access your array elements. So, please, profile first. Otherwise any answer we give here will be most likely wrong.

Comment: @Richard I didn't imply that you did :) just information I had :) For all we know, 2d-array is faster *in this case*

Comment: okay, I will stop here. we dont have the performance problem yet. its all on drawing board so far, so we just try to avoid structural stupidty from the beginning and this one spawned a discussion.

Comment: I have tried (lower is better): one-D=498; two-D=958; jagged=526; unsafe=512. I was wrong about the jagged, because it seems that making an explicit multiplication is better. However, once again the unsafe way does not worth the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd bet on the jagged arrays, unless the Amax or Bmax are a power of 2.

I'd say so, because a jagged array needs two indexed accesses, thus very fast. The other forms implies a multiplication, either implicit or explicit. Unless that multiplication is a simple shift, I think could be a bit heavier than a couple of indexed accesses.

EDIT: Here is the small program used for the test:

```
class Program
{
    private static int A = 10;
    private static int B = 100;

    private static byte[] _linear;
    private static byte[,] _square;
    private static byte[][] _jagged;



    unsafe static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //init arrays
        _linear = new byte[A * B];
        _square = new byte[A, B];
        _jagged = new byte[A][];
        for (int i = 0; i < A; i++)
            _jagged[i] = new byte[B];

        //set-up the params
        var sw = new Stopwatch();
        byte b;
        const int N = 100000;

        //one-dim array (buffer)
        sw.Restart();
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            for (int r = 0; r < A; r++)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < B; c++)
                {
                    b = _linear[r * B + c];
                }
            }
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("linear={0}", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        //two-dim array
        sw.Restart();
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            for (int r = 0; r < A; r++)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < B; c++)
                {
                    b = _square[r, c];
                }
            }
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("square={0}", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        //jagged array
        sw.Restart();
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            for (int r = 0; r < A; r++)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < B; c++)
                {
                    b = _jagged[r][c];
                }
            }
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("jagged={0}", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        //one-dim array within unsafe access (and context)
        sw.Restart();
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            for (int r = 0; r < A; r++)
            {
                fixed (byte* offset = &_linear[r * B])
                {
                    for (int c = 0; c < B; c++)
                    {
                        b = *(byte*)(offset + c);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("unsafe={0}", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        Console.Write("Press any key...");
        Console.ReadKey();
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Amax or Bmax is just the length of the two dimensions, and they will not be the power of 2 very often (only if we are lucky from time to time). So okay, jagged it is.

Comment: which one would you put first then? does it matter? large before small or oppersite? we need ALL data from the small in each look up. Consider this: we might have 100 of these tables and using the same lookup index inside them all (lets say lookup=2345), then we pull 20 values from byte[lookup=2345][20:values] or byte[20:values][lookup=2345] ???

Comment: @BerggreenDK remember to cache the current line in the first loop to reduce indexer operations, if iterating in order. E.g. `for(...) { var line = arr[i]; for (...) { var elem = line[j]; } }`

Comment: Although Jagged arrays are good for maintainable data structures it isn't as simple as an indexer operation - remember the CLR has to do null checking, bounds checking, etc. This adds a significant amount of overhead to each indexer you do. Algebraic arrays would be faster because of this (but less maintainable).

Comment: I consider the question as informative, because I usually prefer to sacrifice the performance than the readiness/form.
Anyway, it does not matter which array is the first: it's an access that costs in equal manner. I also agree with Jonathan (and others) about the fuzziness of the jagged arrays (better: array in general).

Comment: @Mario Vernari: thanks for your testresults. Whats the "unsafe" from your results?

Comment: FYI, I've added the source of the program used for the test.

Comment: AWESOME WORK !!! great!!! I'll bet this will save a LOT of people some time next time they need to make a choice! Much appriciated!

Comment: entered my own values for the test and got these: linear:81531, square:156547, jagged:87160 and unsafe:81014 ... so the loss from using jagged is rather minimal and a great option if you dont want to write ugly code. Using the unsafe is not what we are looking for, so the fastest would be linear.

Comment: @MarioVernari: Reread the question. In this scenario, the array is a lookup table which maps a lot of keys to a chunk of values and the chunk is always read whole. So unless all the data fits into a single memory page, it _does_ make a difference which way around you access the data. Here's a gist to illustrate: https://gist.github.com/diab0l/042e47d1902a897263ec

Comment: @M.Stramm I agree, but what's the point? In any case of huge blocks of data you can have the paging problem. I mean the question was about the "generic" approach, so I can't rely on any optimization.

Comment: @MarioVernari: The point was that if you layout your data sequentially, you may still run into the paging problem. If you spread it across pages, you will force the problem to manifest itself. And that applies "generically". It is not an optimization you rely on, it's more of a mistake you shouldn't make.

Comment: @M.Stramm:Again, I don't see any difference between my snippet and your considerations on the gist, expect for the optimization. Of course, here's not because the comparison wouldn't be reliable. Where is my mistake?

Comment: @MarioVernari: Oh no, it's not the code you posted which is wrong. I was referring to your comment (no.5 from the top) "Anyway, it does not matter which array is the first: it's an access that costs in equal manner." which is obviously wrong, because it does matter which array is first :)

Answer (score 2):

- Multidimensional (`[,]`) arrays are nearly always the slowest, unless under a heavy random access scenario. In theory they shouldn't be, but it's one of the CLR oddities.
- Jagged arrays (`[][]`) are nearly always faster than multidimensional arrays; even under random access scenarios. These have a memory overhead.
- Singledimensional (`[]`) and algebraic arrays (`[y * stride + x]`) are the fastest for random access in safe code.
- Unsafe code is, normally, fastest in all cases (provided you don't pin it repeatedly).

Comment: "Unsafe code is, obviously, the fastest in all cases". I don't think so. Try yourself, and you'll be surprised (C# speaking).

Comment: You skip bounds checking; which is the slowest part of arrays.

Comment: That's right, but the unsafe way requires the array to be pinned with the "fixed" statement, which is slow. Also, well, it depends on how you want to have access to the array: bitmap access (so fixed once), or random access (fixed every time).

Comment: @Mario - Fixed doesn't actually pin the memory, it uses a clever trick to avoid it.  In spite of the documentation.  No bounds checking either, it is fast and dangerous with perf like C arrays.

Answer (score 1):

The only useful answer to "which *X* is faster" (for all X) is: you have to do performance tests that reflect your requirements.

And remember to consider, *in general*<sup>*</sup>:

- Maintenance of the program. If this is not a quick one off, a slightly slower but maintainable program is a better option in most cases.
- Micro benchmarks can be deceptive. For instance a tight loop just reading from a collection might be optimised away in ways not possible when real work is being done.

Additionally consider that you need to look at the complete program to decide where to optimise. Speeding up a loop by 1% might be useful for that loop, but if it is only 1% of the complete runtime then it is not making much differences.

---

<sup>*</sup> But all rules have exceptions.

Comment: This is good general advice, but doesn't answer the question which is quite specific about optimizing performance of accesses to 2-dimensional chunks of data in C#, which has quite a specific answer.

Answer (score 0):

On most modern computers, arithmetic operations are far, far faster than memory lookups.
If you fetch a memory address that isn't in a cache or where the out of order execution pulls from the wrong place you are looking at 10-100 clocks, a pipelined multiply is 1 clock.
The other issue is cache locality.
byte[B*Amax + A] datalist4;  seems like the best bet if you are accessing with A's varying sequentially.
When datalist4[b*Amax + a] is accessed, the computer will usually start pulling in datalist4[b*Amax + a+ 64/sizeof(dataListType)], ... +128 ... etc, or if it detects a reverse iteration, datalist4[b*Amax + a - 64/sizeof(dataListType)]

Hope that helps!

Answer (score -2):

May be best way for u will be use HashMap

[Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/xfhwa508.aspx)?

Comment: too complex a datastructure, considering our need of simple bytearrays and an index.